# Execute python from Crontab in AWS Lightsail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-lightsail

I was trying to run a Python script from the linux terminal at AWS Ligthsail without success.

```
I tried multiple options and still can't get it to run:

* * * * *  /usr/bin/python3 path/to/my/script.py

and within the .py script

#/usr/bin/python3

I also tried:
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 path/to/my && ./script.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your cron schedule expression, it should be five stars `*`, like  `* * * * *` to be excuted every minute , but in your example you are using just four stars which is wrong .

in cron expressions each line has five time-and-date fields followed by a username (if this is the system crontab file), and followed by a command.

The time and date fields are:

1. minute  :  0-59
2. hour   : 0-23
3. day of month   : 1-31
4. month  : 1-12 (or names)
5. day of week    : 0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)

you can read more [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) , and you can use this [website](https://crontab.guru/) to generate and experience with crontab schedule expressions .

**So** you may need to update your cron schedule expression :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 path/to/my/script.py
```

Comment: Sorry I put 4 *, I tried 5 * but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok .. that's weird ! did you  tried to make the script excutable  : `sudo chmod u+x script.py`  and add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the very begining of the script than use this `*  *  *  *  *  path/to/my/script.py` in cron job?

Answer (score 1):

When putting the result of the cron I could see that in the .py I had to specify a path. Now it works!

```
* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python3 path/to/my/script.py >> path/to/my/script.py/out.txt  2>&1
```

Comment: so that did it :D you didn't mention that your script has output